# Checkout style state / country dropdown select

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, drop-downs

I want to add a style to the country or state dropdown in the checkout page, how I can add a style for the option on :hover for example?

```
.opc-index-index .opc-wrapper-opc .form-list select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) url("../img/down_arrow.png") no-repeat scroll right 5px center;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Muli",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.opc-index-index .opc-wrapper-opc .form-list select:focus{
background: rgba(212,212,212,1) url("../img/down_arrow.png") no-repeat scroll right 5px center;
color: white
}


.opc-index-index .opc-wrapper-opc .form-list select:focus{
background: rgba(177,177,177,1) url("../img/down_arrow.png") no-repeat scroll right 5px center;
color: white
}
```

Product view page:

```
    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
    <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
    <div class="input-box">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
              </select>

          </div>
    </dd>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>").select2({
    placeholder: "Select Size"
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download from https://select2.github.io/
extract zip file and upload below files to your skin folder

`select2-4.0.3\dist\js\select2.full.min.js`

`skin/frontend/your-package/your_theme/js/select2/select2.full.min.js`

`select2-4.0.3\dist\css\select2.min.css`

`skin/frontend/your-package/your_theme/css/select2/select2.min.css`

now edit local.xml

`app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml`

```
<default>
    ..........your existing code..

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/select2/select2.min.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/select2/select2.full.min.js</name><params/></action>
    </reference>

    ..........your existing code..

</default>
```

Add script to below file
`app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#billing:country_id").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a Country"
    });

    $("#billing:region_id").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a Country"
    });

    $("#billing:country_id").change(function(){
        $("#billing:region_id").select2("destroy");

        $("#billing:region_id").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a Country"
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Code Not Tested

Comment: take a look I add what I do, but I need to style only the option not the entire select

Comment: @RobertD you can not style option of select but either you can use third party Js to convert Select to <ul><li> list and then you can design <li>

Comment: You can use https://select2.github.io/examples.html and https://select2.github.io/

Comment: if I use this script that dropdown will not work anymore, you test this?

Comment: You need to work around it, I had used it many times

Comment: can you show me an example how I can add that in the checkout page? for country and state?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I think is perfect is work can you tell me if I can add the same in the product page? for size?

Comment: yup, you can do same thing for size. Please accept it as answer if it works for you, so it can helpful for others too

Comment: I do the same, but the dropdown was transform in span and magento functionality stop work.

Comment: is dropdown appears or not? and is any error in browser console?

Comment: can you take a look I edit my post with what I add for the product page dropdown, but the price is not updating when you select any value from that dropdown

Comment: are you here, the code is not working, there was my mistake I add some css on select directly, and when I put your code I think that is okay, but now is not, the code is not working

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery (it's probably already loaded anyway) and add a class for the options in the select you want to change. Something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#your-select-id option").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("your-css-class");
 });
});
```

and then style appropriately in css

Comment: Hi thank you is not work, you try it?

Comment: I have something similar on one of my sites working OK. Did you replace "your-select-id" with the html id attribute of the select (possibly "shipping:region_id" but your may be different)? Where did you put the script. Mine is in System>Config>Design>Miscellaneous Scripts. You'll need to wrap it in <script> tags too.